# Styling single <a> to match grouped-input (controlgroup)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Using j[Query Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com): I had one control group, and did some CSS styling to it. I created another control group and need the style to match the first (control group). The elements in the control group are different.

I need help creating the same styling for both control groups.

**1. First control group**

CSS:

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 42px;
}
.ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-select {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    right: 73px;
}
.ui-controlgroup-controls a.ui-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    left: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
    <option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>
  </select>
  <a href="" id="iconshow" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
</div>
```

**2. Second control group**

*I need the same styling as above for this one*

HTML:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a href="#" data-role="button">Select Location</a>
  <a href="" id="mailLocationDetails" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" style = "display:none">Add</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you initialize a plugin on first group? It looks like it. If ya, then call it on second one too

Comment: I am not clear. Can you please explain what should I need to do ?

Comment: It looks like jQuery mobile added classes to apply some specific style. In your posted HTML markup, no element is targeted by any CSS rule so your question is really confusing. Now, i'm not a jQuery mobile expert so i'm not sure what happen here

Comment: @A.Wolff you were right about the javascript lib in the OP's question. I linked the external `jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1` in the fiddle to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Description: Add classes `ui-btn2` and `ui-btn3` from the example to the first `<a data-role="button"`. `ui-btn2` adjusts the width, while `ui-btn3` adjusts the right border radius. Both classes could be combined, but are kept separate for this example.

See it here: <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/XBxP5/)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn2 ui-btn3">Select Location</a>
  <a href="" id="mailLocationDetails" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" style="display:none">Add</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* width */
.ui-controlgroup-controls a.ui-btn2 {
    left: 15px;
}
/* right radius */
.ui-controlgroup-controls a.ui-btn3 {
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class to both the control groups and give the style.

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup-controls">


.ui-controlgroup-controls
{
    // Style for control-group with class abc goes here
}
```

Comment: Give class name ui-controlgroup-controls instead of abc here. Which is a defined class in your stylesheet

Comment: @user3300593 I have edited my answer by replacing abc with your class name ui-controlgroup-controls

Comment: `.ui-controlgroup-controls` is a class added dynamically to `controlgroup` elements wrapper.